# How can I send items to a Kotlin.Flow (like a Behaviorsubject)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.channels, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I wanted to know how can I send/emit items to a `Kotlin.Flow`, so my use case is:

In the consumer/ViewModel/Presenter I can *subscribe* with the `collect`  function:

```
fun observe() {
 coroutineScope.launch {
    // 1. Send event
    reopsitory.observe().collect {
      println(it)
    }
  }
}
```

But the issue is in the `Repository` side, with RxJava we could use a [Behaviorsubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) expose it as an `Observable/Flowable` and emit new items like this:

```
behaviourSubject.onNext(true)
```

But whenever I build a new flow:

```
flow {

}
```

I can only *collect*. How can I send values to a flow?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to get the *latest* value on subscription/collection you should use a [ConflatedBroadcastChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-conflated-broadcast-channel/):

```
private val channel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<Boolean>()
```

This will replicate `BehaviourSubject`, to expose the channel as a Flow:

```
// Repository
fun observe() {
  return channel.asFlow()
}
```

Now to send an event/value to that exposed `Flow` simple send to this channel.

```
// Repository
fun someLogicalOp() {
  channel.send(false) // This gets sent to the ViewModel/Presenter and printed.
}
```

Console:

> false

If you wish to only receive values **after** you start collecting you should use a `BroadcastChannel` instead.

### To make it clear:

Behaves as an Rx's `PublishedSubject`

```
private val channel = BroadcastChannel<Boolean>(1)

fun broadcastChannelTest() {
  // 1. Send event
  channel.send(true)

  // 2. Start collecting
  channel
    .asFlow()
    .collect {
      println(it)
    }

  // 3. Send another event
  channel.send(false)
}
```

> false

*Only* `false` gets printed as the first event was sent **before** `collect { }`.

---

Behaves as an Rx's `BehaviourSubject`

```
private val confChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<Boolean>()

fun conflatedBroadcastChannelTest() {
  // 1. Send event
  confChannel.send(true)

  // 2. Start collecting
  confChannel
    .asFlow()
    .collect {
      println(it)
    }

  // 3. Send another event
  confChannel.send(false)
}
```

> true
>
> false

Both events are printed, you always get the **latest** value (if present).

Also, want to mention Kotlin's team development on `DataFlow` (name pending):

- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/1354

Which seems better suited to this use case (as it will be a [cold stream](https://medium.com/@elizarov/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9)).

Comment: Could you show us an example of what a test for the `BroadcastChannel` above would look like?

Comment: Check this example here on the Google Android Developer's blog: (Chapter .5) - https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/lessons-learnt-using-coroutines-flow-4a6b285c0d06?

Comment: Don't we need `.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)`?

Comment: Just recently the [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/index.html) (which was a `DataFlow` in the answer) was introduced in a [coroutines release 1.3.6](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/1.3.6), so maybe give it a try

Comment: @V1raNi It isn't even available in Kotlin!

Comment: Still in DEV, it will be eventually released.

Comment: For `PublishSubject` behavior, there's an upcoming official support for this called "SharedFlow" which is currently in PR right now.

See it here https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/2069

Discussion of original idea can be found here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1082

Comment: Yes I'll update the answer as soon it is official. You can read from the other comments mentioning it. Also, this was a year ago :)

Comment: Note: This API is obsolete since 1.5.0. It will be deprecated with warning in 1.6.0 and with error in 1.7.0. It is replaced with StateFlow.

Answer (score 22):

Take a look at [MutableStateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/index.html) documentation as it is a replacement for `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` that is going to be deprecated, very soon.

For a better context, look at the [whole discussion on the original issue on Kotlin's repository on Github](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1973).

Comment: Still in @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi -- I'll update the accepted answer as soon as it is stable.

Comment: @JoaquimLey, `StateFlow` [has become stable](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/c35ce7e509ff284f4b33ed20a0026e5149ca17a9/CHANGES.md#version-140) in the coroutines `1.4.0` version.

Comment: The bad thing about MutableStateFlow, it is works like distinctUntilchanges. You cant emit the same value. But sometimes you need.

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE**:

Kotlin Coroutines `1.4.0` is now available with `MutableSharedFlow`, which replaces the need for `Channel`. `MutableSharedFlow` cleanup is also built in so you don't need to manually OPEN & CLOSE it, unlike `Channel`. Please use `MutableSharedFlow` if you need a Subject-like api for `Flow`

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Since your question had the `android` tag I'll add an Android implementation that allows you to easily create a `BehaviorSubject` or a `PublishSubject` that handles its own lifecycle.

This is relevant in Android because you don't want to forget to close the channel and leak memory. This implementation avoids the need to explicitly "dispose" of the reactive stream by tying it to the creation and destruction of the Fragment/Activity. Similar to `LiveData`

```
interface EventReceiver<Message> {
    val eventFlow: Flow<Message>
}

interface EventSender<Message> {
    fun postEvent(message: Message)
    val initialMessage: Message?
}

class LifecycleEventSender<Message>(
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val channel: BroadcastChannel<Message>,
    override val initialMessage: Message?
) : EventSender<Message>, LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun postEvent(message: Message) {
        if (!channel.isClosedForSend) {
            coroutineScope.launch { channel.send(message) }
        } else {
            Log.e("LifecycleEventSender","Channel is closed. Cannot send message: $message")
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    fun create() {
        channel.openSubscription()
        initialMessage?.let { postEvent(it) }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun destroy() {
        channel.close()
    }
}

class ChannelEventReceiver<Message>(channel: BroadcastChannel<Message>) :
    EventReceiver<Message> {
    override val eventFlow: Flow<Message> = channel.asFlow()
}

abstract class EventRelay<Message>(
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    channel: BroadcastChannel<Message>,
    initialMessage: Message? = null
) : EventReceiver<Message> by ChannelEventReceiver<Message>(channel),
    EventSender<Message> by LifecycleEventSender<Message>(
        lifecycle,
        coroutineScope,
        channel,
        initialMessage
    )
```

By using the `Lifecycle` library from Android, I can now create a `BehaviorSubject` that cleans itself up after the activity/fragment has been destroyed

```
class BehaviorSubject<String>(
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    initialMessage = "Initial Message"
) : EventRelay<String>(
    lifecycle,
    coroutineScope,
    ConflatedBroadcastChannel(),
    initialMessage
)
```

or I can create a `PublishSubject` by using a buffered `BroadcastChannel`

```
class PublishSubject<String>(
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    initialMessage = "Initial Message"
) : EventRelay<String>(
    lifecycle,
    coroutineScope,
    BroadcastChannel(Channel.BUFFERED),
    initialMessage
)
```

And now I can do something like this

```
class MyActivity: Activity() {

    val behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject(
        this@MyActivity.lifecycle,
        this@MyActivity.lifecycleScope
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) { 

            behaviorSubject.eventFlow
                .onEach { stringEvent ->
                    Log.d("BehaviorSubjectFlow", stringEvent)
                    // "BehaviorSubjectFlow: Initial Message"
                    // "BehaviorSubjectFlow: Next Message"
                }
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
                .launchIn(this@MyActivity.lifecycleScope)

        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        behaviorSubject.postEvent("Next Message")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right it had the android tag, maybe my mistake but your answer does not reply to the question. I haven't tried but I think it is outside of the scope also, with that implementation how would one test the behaviorSubject or the presenter?

Comment: "..your answer does not reply to the question." The question was, "I can only collect. How can I send values to a flow?" You can't "send" values to a `Flow`, in the same way you can't send values to an `Observable`. You need the equivalent of a `Subject`. But there is nothing like a `Subject` with the same semantics in the coroutines library at the time of this answer, but is coming soon.

Comment: "I haven't tried but I think it is outside of the scope" I would give ti a try. The implementation of a "BehaviorSubject" I proposed does exactly what you would expect from an Rx BehaviorSubject, but uses a BroadcastChannel as the backing reactive stream.

Comment: "with that implementation how would one test the behaviorSubject or the presenter?"
I added the "Presenter" just to show that you can freely inject "behaviorSubject" into any view layer architecture, but now that I am seeing the answer again I agree that it is not necessary to the answer. Will remove. As for how I would test the "behaviorSubject" I can show the tests I use to test the expected behavior in a separate thread.

Comment: Probably best, I do appreciate your take but most likely not really directed to THIS specific question.